# How to get value without surrounding tags from XML using xpath

Tags: xml, bash, shell, perl, xpath

E.g.

```
$ echo '<a> <b>value</b> </a>' | xpath -n -q -e '/a/b'
<b>value</b>
$
```

What I want is to print only `value` and not  `<b>value</b>`

I'm open to using something other than `xpath`, but not regex as I want to treat XML as XML not string.

I'm trying to extract an auth token that I get in an XML response for a `curl` command.

Comment: `'/a/b/text()'`?

Comment: @JaSON Yes, it does! Thank you.